# Make runit-init silent

Tags: boot, grub, runit, artix-linux

[image: boot message]

Is there a way to silence the runit-init?
I managed to silence runit it self by redirecting output but i think this is caused by runit-init...

*I put the banner there in process 1 , just a simple printf, i just want to se this banner , not any other info that runit gives.

Info:
I use runit as my init system, runit 2.1.2-27
The way i redirected the output, in etc/runit/1 , i added `> /dev/null 2>&1` to the run_sysinit function.

Comment: Did you redirect stderr too? Please tell us if you are using sysvd or systemd or ... And the runinit version.

Comment: Added more info now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At that stage there is no redirection yet (we are talking about process 1. There are at least two options though to solve that:

Rebuild the package for your distribution. After you download the source and before you rebuild the package, change `runit-2.1.2-27/src/strerr_die.c` so that `strerr_warn()` does nothing (just remove the whole body).

The other option is to clear the screen before you show your banner. You will briefly see some output, but it will be erased right away. The command `clear` should do it in a portable way, but you can also output the escape sequence for the console with something like `echo -e '\033[2J'`.

Comment: Clear will do for now thank you very much! I will try the first method also when i find time, maybe i can also make a pull request for everyone else how want's this feature.

Comment: If the answer helped you, consider marking it as useful. If it solved your problem, you can choose it as the accepted answer.